# Placing UIImageView on top of the UIView, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, ios

Say you have a `UIView` on top of which you have a bunch of cards allocated in some order. When something interesting happens you'd like to display another card at some location.

Only condition is :

- Card needs to show up on top of whatever exists in that location
- Card location need to be stared in terms of the `UIView`

[image]

So, i'd like 10 of hearts to:

- Appear on top of Jack of Diamonds
- Be in that location relative to the main view

Currently what i have is (shows up ok, but is wrong)

```
  [[card faceImageView] addSubview:[followUpCard 
          faceImageViewAtPoint:CGPointMake(15, 25)]];
```

If i do

```
  [gameView addSubview:[followUpCard 
          faceImageViewAtPoint:CGPointMake(250, 150)]]; //coord in superview's system
```

If card would appear at the very bottom.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you just want to bring the card to the foreground?

If so you could do something like this:

```
[[followUpCard superview] bringSubviewToFront:followUpCard];
```